# Disable middle mouse click paste in an iframe

Tags: html, iframe, ckeditor

Is it possible to disable middle mouse click paste in an iframe

```
<iframe id="ck_id"></iframe>
```

I have disabled the context menu using:

```
document.getElementById("ck_id").contentWindow.document.oncontextmenu = function(){alert("Disabled context menu"); return false;};
```

Comment: Can you show your approach and its outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery 'mousedown':

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ck_id").contents().find("body").on('mousedown', function (e) {
            if (e.which == 2) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //Do your work
            }
        });
    });
```